# How Use Hammer.js Touch Area with Jade

Tags: html, meteor, pug, meteor-blaze, hammer.js

I'd like to use the Hammer.js package (https://atmospherejs.com/chriswessels/hammer) in my Meteor + Blaze + Jade app, but I can't get the touch area inside the handlebars to close with {{/HammerTouchArea}}

```
{{#HammerTouchArea gestureMap=templateGestures}}
  #main-page(style="{{backgroundImage}}")
    +yield
```

My Google-fu has yielded nothing which is surprising for what I imagine to be a common use-case of Jade + Hammer.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this in a closed issue on the Hammer.js repo and the app is building now:

```
+HammerTouchArea(gestureMap=templateGestures)
```

Source: https://github.com/chriswessels/meteor-hammer/issues/18